# where clause in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, where-clause

i am using sqlite3.

this query is't  workin for me

```
SELECT * FROM tablename where Rank > 5  and Statid='0 & 1';
```

here i want to select all those records wit statid 0 and 1 . how shld i do this???

Comment: does Statid contain numbers or text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

did you mean :

```
  SELECT * FROM tablename where Rank > 5  and Statid in (0,1);
```

Comment: your welcome if its help upvote this as the right answer by click on the right answer mark